# What does this "*:down" mean when using linux cmd "lsof" in Centos?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, centos

I try to check a process fd using the linux cmd "lsof" in centos.

```
lsof -p 22316 | grep -i tcp
confd   22316 root   39u  IPv4 18144132       0t0      TCP localhost:4565 (LISTEN)
confd   22316 root   42u  IPv4 18144134       0t0      TCP *:down (LISTEN)
```

I don't understand well about "*:down"
I believe that * means all IPs of this host, then what is the port number of "down"?

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are translated to names using `/etc/services`, which contains the [IANA service and port number](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) database (or at least a subset thereof). You can query it with `getent service` or `grep`. (You can also use `lsof -P` to disable port name translation entirely.)

According to this database, service name `down` is assigned to TCP port 2022.

(The IANA registration entry doesn't mention what it's *officially* used for, but that doesn't matter – most likely your program just used port 2022 because it looked nice.)

Comment: Yeah, I use -P and I can see it is 2022. Thanks very much.